# Periodicity of Newton's method approximations on a cubic polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Bruckner & Bruckner, Elementary Real Analysis

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 3$

Applying Newton's method to get $x_{n+1} = x_n -\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \ ,$ prove that for any positive integer $p$, there exists a starting value $\theta$ such that the sequence is periodic ( with $p$ being the length of each period). Periodicity is defined as the property of a sequence such that $x_n = x_{n+p}$ for all $n$.

If I define $$g(x)= x - \frac{x^3 - 3x +3 }{3x^2 - 3}$$

then for each $g^p(x)$ = $g(g(g(...g(x)$, there must be an $x$ such that $x = g^p(x)$. Graphically, I know that each $g^p(x)$ must cross over the $x=y$ diagonal, but that doesn't tell me anything. I know that $g()$ ranges over $\Re,$ and is undefined at 1, -1. All answers or just hints appreciated.